# Confused About Pointers in C and changing data at memory addresses

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I think I will understand this concept better if someone can assist me in a current project that I'm working on.  I want to use C to edit data at specific memory addresses, using pointers.  Specifically, I have two character arrays (strings) which I need to both read data from at specific locations, and also write to at specific locations.

I'm mostly confused about syntax of pointers, such as `*` and `->` and `&`.

From my understanding, the `*` refers to the data kept at the current memory address of the pointer.  So, for example, if I wanted to edit the data at the beginning memory address of a `char *p`, I would do something like:    `(*p) = 'c';`

Now, what if I wanted do to alter a character at the *2nd* memory address from the beginning of `p`?

Also, I understand that `&` refers to the location of the pointer.  But I don't know how to use this syntax.

Here is my example:

```
   int orig_length = strlen(original_string); //-1 for \0?
char *poriginal, *pnew_string;

poriginal = &original_string; 

while(orig_length>0) {
 k = 0;
 j = 0;
 while(isalpha(*(poriginal+j))) { 
   j++;
   k++;
 }
 while(k > 0) {
   *(pnew_string+(j-k)) = toupper(*(poriginal+k-1)); //toupper
   k--;
 }
 if(*(poriginal+(j)) == '_') { 
   *(pnew_string+(j)) = ' '; 
 }
 else {
   *(pnew_string+(j)) = *(poriginal+(j)); 
 }
 orig_length = orig_length - j;
}
*(pnew_string+strlen(pnew_string)) = '\0'; //Syn? Is this actually necessary? 
... //program continues...
```

By the way, this program is meant to take one string "now_i_understand!" and reverse each word, capitalize each word, switch _ to ' ', and leave other punctuation alone:  "WON I DNATSREDNU!"

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone.  I'll edit what I have above to show what I have now.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are dealing with is an array of characters (and it is), use array syntax:

```
pnew_string[j+1] = poriginal[j+1];
```

Note that this syntax is equivalent to:

```
*(pnew_string + j + 1) = *(poriginal + j + 1);
```

but is more readable.

Dealing with most of the other cases you've got should be obvious given this example.

Comment: Thank you, this confirmed the path I was heading on from researching on google.  Can you actually answer me another question, though?  I'm worried about this line:  poriginal = &original_string;        would this set poriginal pointing to the memory location of original_string?

Comment: It's impossible to say whether it'd have the intended effect or not without knowing whether `original_string` is a pointer or an array. (If pointer: No. If array: Yes.)

Answer (score 1):

The `*` and `&` operators are inverses of each other. A pointer object hold the *address* of some other object in memory (or it old a *null pointer*, which doesn't point to any object).

The unary `*` operator takes a pointer operand, and gives you the object that it points to; this is called *dereferencing*.

The unary `&` operator takes an operand that refers to an object of any type, and gives you a pointer to that object. `&` is the *address-of* operator.

For example:

```
int obj = 42; /* obj is an object of type int; it currently holds the value 42 */
int *ptr;     /* ptr is a pointer to an int */
ptr = &obj;   /* ptr now holds the address of obj */
printf("obj = %d\n", obj); /* prints 42 */
printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr); /* also prints 42; *ptr is another name for obj */
```

The `->` operator is shorthand for dereferencing a pointer and accessing a member of what it points to. The prefix must be a pointer to a struct or union. `foo->bar` means the same thing as `(*foo).bar`, where `foo` is a pointer and `bar` is the name of a member of what `foo` points to.

You can also perform arithmetic on pointers. If `ptr` is a pointer pointing to an element of an array, then `ptr + 1` points to the next element of the array, `ptr + 2` points to the element after that, and so forth.

The `[]` array indexing operator is actually defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. `ptr[2]` means exactly the same thing as `*(ptr+2)`. Combine that with the fact that an array name, in most contexts, decays to a pointer to the array's first element, and with a little thought you'll see how `arr[2]` refers to the third element of the array `arr` (third because indexing starts at `0`).

I strongly recommend sections 4 (Pointers) and 6 (Arrays and Pointers) of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/); it will likely explain this stuff better than I have.